# Put rows in between existed rows, and interpolate the values in the data frame

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, matrix, interpolation

[image]

Hello.
I would like you to ask how to put new rows ( 60 number of new rows ) in between every existed rows.
What I am thinking of is as shown as in the picture.

I want to put new rows in between every existed rows, and interpolate the values.

Can you guide me how to do this?

I am using Pandas, and Numpy libraries

Thank you.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can multiple index values by `3`, then [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for add missing values and last use [`DataFrame.interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html):

```
#solution working with default index
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

df = df.rename(lambda x: x * 3).reindex(np.arange(df.index.max() * 3 + 1)).interpolate()
```

Comment: thank you for your comment. Then what values I must change for putting 60 rows in between existed rows?

Comment: @손상우 - I think instead `3` use `61`, because 1 existing + 60 new rows